# Simple boost program with nvcc - error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, boost, makefile, cuda

**Background**

I want to use boost library to serialize some objects in cuda. I have a bigger Makefile with nvcc compiling about 20 files. I hope to write the smallest working example of Makefile with boost library and then add it to my larger makefile

***Boost library localization***
[image]

**Makefile**

```
LIBS=--relocatable-device-code=true -lcusolver -lcusparse 
ARCH=-arch=sm_30
OPTIONS= -O2



hello: main.o 
    nvcc $(OPTIONS) $(ARCH) $(LIBS) -L${BOOST_ROOT}/lib/ -llibboost main.o -o hello 

main.o: main.cpp
    nvcc $(OPTIONS) $(ARCH) $(LIBS) -c main.cpp -o main.o
    

clean:
    rm -rf *.o hello.*
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
using namespace std;


int main() {

    boost::optional<string>;

    return 0;
}
```

***Running***
`make hello && ./hello`

***Error which I get***

```
[ test]$ make hello && ./hello
nvcc -O2 -arch=sm_30 --relocatable-device-code=true -lcusolver -lcusparse  -c main.cpp -o main.o
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:8:12: error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
     boost::optional<string>;
            ^
make: *** [main.o] Error
```

Comment: This isn't really unique or specific to `nvcc` or CUDA. The GNU compiler toolchain would [report](https://godbolt.org/z/av4MzK5Kj)  the same error for the same code. In fact, this error report is coming from a GNU compiler component, being used by `nvcc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not given your variable a name. Try changing it to:

```cpp
boost::optional<string> exampleName;
```